# im trying to add background images to my while scroll animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have been trying to figure out how to add background images in  combination with the sliding sections/text. So far I only have the images attached to the sections but I think the way I have my js written is messing things up. I know that it's a better practice to put the images as backgrounds in css but I'm still a rookie and just trying to make my landing page neat.

This is my first project. Any help is appreciated.

(https://codepen.io/Robertthegreat12/pen/XWGbVbr)

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #131316;
  color: #ffffff;
}

img {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.btn-posnawr {
  color: #192022;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 250px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  font: normal 18px/60px 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.btn-posnawr span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00abec;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out, height 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out, height 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn-posnawr:hover {
  color: #eee;
}

.btn-posnawr:hover span {
  width: 225%;
  height: 562.5px;
}

.btn-posnawr:active {
  background-color: #00c4ad;
}

.box {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(4px);
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

#slide1 {
  background-image: url();
}
```

```html
<section class="box" id="slide1">
  <h2>Be Up To Date</h2>
  <p>with our page you will be able to stay up tp date with the latest manga news</p>
  <img class="akira" src="/Users/robertduverge/Downloads/javascfript from rob /akirabg.jpeg">
</section>
<section class="box" id="slide2">
  <h2>Read some of your favorites</h2>
  <p>although our stock is limited i assure you we have some of the best picks out there</p>
  <img src="/Users/robertduverge/Downloads/javascfript from rob /yusukemuratabg2.jpeg">
</section>
<section class="box" id="slide3">
  <h2>... And by that i mean most are my favorites ;) </h2>
  <img src="/Users/robertduverge/Downloads/javascfript from rob /onepunchmanbg.jpeg">
</section>
<section class="box" id="slide4">
  <h2>Find your taste</h2>
  <p>from action to comedy,adventure,romance,horror,fantasy</p>
  <img src="/Users/robertduverge/Downloads/javascfript from rob /fmabg.webp">
</section>
<section class="box" id="slide5">
  <h2>hey this is try out </h2>
  <p>this will be changed later afetr i put the images in </p>
  <img src="/Users/robertduverge/Downloads/javascfript from rob /yusukemuratamashupbg.webp">
</section>
<section class="box" id="slide6">
  <h2> For anime fans </h2>
  <p> this store is perfect for anime fans who want to jump into manga. Enjoy</p>
  <img src="/Users/robertduverge/Downloads/javascfript from rob /isaacneterobg.jpeg">
  <button class="btn-posnawr" href="#">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-kiwi-bird"></i>
  visit shop<span>yay</span>
  </button>
</section>
```

I tried putting IDs in the sections and tried to modify it but it didn't do anything.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Did you add an actual image in `background-image:url()` ? Perhaps you don't see the image because `#slide1` has no width / height?

Comment: hey thanks for the help i will def try to see if maybe the no height and width thing is the issue, im trying to have my images slowly fade in with the text while scrolling like a nice image change effect per section, but i don't know how to insert each different image into each different section

Answer (score 0):

To add a background image to each section, excluding the first one, use the `background` property with the `nth-child` selector. This also avoids the need to manually add an ID and and image tag to each section.

```css
main section:nth-child(n + 2) {
  background: no-repeat center url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595147389795-37094173bfd8?q=80&w=2069&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

To target a specific section, such as section 3:

```css
main section:nth-child(3) {
// do something
}
```

Here's the full code:

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add('show');
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove('show');
    }
  });
});

const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));









(function() {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-posnawr");

  buttons.forEach(button => {
    ["mouseenter", "mouseout"].forEach(evt => {
      button.addEventListener(evt, e => {
        let parentOffset = button.getBoundingClientRect(),
          relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left,
          relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

        const span = button.getElementsByTagName("span");

        span[0].style.top = relY + "px";
        span[0].style.left = relX + "px";
      });
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #131316;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-posnawr {
  color: #192022;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 250px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  font: normal 18px/60px "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.btn-posnawr span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00abec;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out, height 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out, height 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn-posnawr:hover {
  color: #eee;
}

.btn-posnawr:hover span {
  width: 225%;
  height: 562.5px;
}

.btn-posnawr:active {
  background-color: #00c4ad;
}

.box {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(4px);
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}


/* add background images to all sections excluding first one */

main section:nth-child(n + 2) {
  background: no-repeat center url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595147389795-37094173bfd8?q=80&w=2069&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
  background-size: cover;
}


/* add background image for 3rd section */


/* main section:nth-child(3) {
  background: no-repeat center url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQq70AvDs-OIZrlcU0kAqvObihT8VhvedCurSyXCDCakQ&s");
}

/* add background image for 4th section */


/* main section:nth-child(4) {
  background: no-repeat center
    url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQq70AvDs-OIZrlcU0kAqvObihT8VhvedCurSyXCDCakQ&s");
}
 */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script defer src="javascript.js"></script>
  <title>Manga Central</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header1">
      <h1 id="main-text">Manga Central</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h2>
        <p>Welcome to MANGA CENTRAL a place where you can enjoy your favorite mangas and </p>
      </h2>
    </section>

    <section class="box" id="slide1">
      <h2>Be Up To Date</h2>
      <p>with our page you will be able to stay up tp date with the latest manga news</p>
    </section>

    <section class="box" id="slide2">
      <h2>Read some of your favorites</h2>
      <p>although our stock is limited i assure you we have some of the best picks out there</p>
    </section>

    <section class="box" id="slide3">
      <h2>... And by that i mean most are my favorites ;) </h2>
    </section>

    <section class="box" id="slide4">
      <h2>Find your taste</h2>
      <p>from action to comedy,adventure,romance,horror,fantasy</p>
    </section>

    <section class="box" id="slide5">
      <h2>hey this is try out </h2>
      <p>this will be changed later afetr i put the images in </p>
    </section>

    <section class="box" id="slide6">
      <h2> For anime fans </h2>
      <p> this store is perfect for anime fans who want to jump into manga. Enjoy</p>
      <button class="btn-posnawr" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-kiwi-bird"></i>visit
        shop<span>yay</span></button>
    </section>

  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: thanks a lot brother i will give it a try in a second